# EnhancedIntentService warning On Incoming Notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, intentservice

I have been getting two errors in my log once a notification is received

```
EnhancedIntentService: Service took too long to process intent: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE App may get closed

EnhancedIntentService: binding to the service failed
```

There is NOTHING on Google of either of these messages or even `EnhancedIntentService`.

Relevant code:

```
    <service
        android:name="---.GcmMCIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

   <service
        android:name="---.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service android:name="---.GCMRegIntentService"
             android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="5">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This is on a 8.0 emulator.  Play Services 11.4.2
Let me know if I can show any other code.  I just find it curious there is nothing on these error messages at all on S.O. or Google.

Comment: Might be due to the Android 8.0 service runtime limitations.

Comment: Since OS 8.0, when app goes in background, OS allocates some time to initiate your service but if it doesn't start during that buffer time then it considers as @GabeSechan said and throws error.

Comment: I have decided to upgrade my app from GCM to FCM so I'm going to see how things will react after this then I will see where this issues stands

Comment: @KickingLettuce I came across your question because I keep getting this message too, and I'M ALREADY USING FCM.
In my case notifications are delivered but with a very big delay if App is in foreground, but not even delivered if App is in background.

Comment: Anyone knows how to solve this